# Monitoring HDFS sink connector lag

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

In the new release of HDFS Sink connector the offset storage has been changed. In old releases I was able to monitor connector lag using Kafka tools for consumer monitoring (like 'kafka-consumer-groups').

But now, I observe this message in our logs:

```
   log.info("HDFS connector does not commit consumer offsets to Kafka. Upon startup, HDFS "
        + "Connector restores offsets from filenames in HDFS. In the absence of files in HDFS, "
        + "the connector will attempt to find offsets for its consumer group in the "
        + "'__consumer_offsets' topic. If offsets are not found, the consumer will "
        + "rely on the reset policy specified in the 'consumer.auto.offset.reset' property to "
        + "start exporting data to HDFS.");
```

So my question is, how could we monitor this connector?

Comment: Enable JMX exports on your Connect Workers. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-196%3A+Add+metrics+to+Kafka+Connect+framework